# VHDL : Can New Operators be Defined?

Tags: vhdl, data-operator

I'm doing something where I'd like to use operators instead of functions with parentheses and I realized I don't know how to do that.  I dug around and can not find a reference that even talks about the difference between operators and functions.  Everything I find simply talks about overloading existing operators.

Browsing the std_logic_1164.vhd source code I noticed the operator function names were all in quotes rather than just written out.  Is that the difference?

I tried constructing a test case, but my VHDL foo isn't working today and I can not for the life of me figure out what I'm doing wrong that it won't even compile.  Seems it's a line with the report statement.  It keeps saying it is expecting an END.  ???  Ok, I spent another 15 minutes on it and found that while assert can be used as a concurrent statement, report can not... duh!

So the test cases work.  2 OR 4 is 6 while 3 OR 7 is 7.

However, when I use the name "Ralph" instead of "OR" I get a compile error, not in the definition, but in the usage.

> Error: COMP96_0019: ../../../../SRC/overload.vhd : (30, 20): Keyword 'when' expected.

So are we indeed not allowed to create new operators?  I suppose if it is not used carefully, it could create problems in programs that worked fine until a signal name was usurped by an operator (although that is always possible with functions) but moreso with the tools.  After it parsed Ralph, it complained that only "when" is allowed, but that should not be a hard issue to deal with I would think.

```
-- overloading test

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;
--use std.textio.all; 

ENTITY Func_Test IS
  GENERIC (
      OutWidth  : positive := 1
    );
  port (
    Din         : in    unsigned (17 downto 0);
    Dout        : out   unsigned (53 downto 0);
    Sample_En   : in    std_logic;
    Clk         : in    std_logic
    );
end Func_Test;

ARCHITECTURE behav OF Func_Test IS 
  signal temp1, temp2 : integer;
  
  function "Ralph" (Left, Right: integer) return integer is
    variable L : signed (31 downto 0) := to_signed(Left, 32); 
    variable R : signed (31 downto 0) := to_signed(Right, 32); 
  begin 
    return to_integer(L or R); 
  end function "Ralph"; 
begin 
  temp1 <= 2 Ralph 4; 
  assert temp1 = 6 report "2 OR 4 /= 6! " & to_hstring(to_signed(temp1, 32));
  
  temp2 <= 3 Ralph 7; 
  assert temp2 = 6 report "3 OR 7 /= 10 " & to_hstring(to_signed(temp2, 32));
END behav;  -- Func_Test
```

Comment: No. IEEE 1076-2008 4.5.2 Operator overloading "The declaration of a function whose designator is an operator symbol is used to overload an operator. The sequence of characters of the operator symbol shall be one of the operators in the operator classes defined in 9.2."  That precludes "Ralph" as an operator.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is operator precedence : allowing adding genuinely new operators like Ralph the Wonder Llama would require some means to allocate a precedence level for them.

So, VHDL simply restricts you to the predefined set of operators. You can overload existing ones, (and they retain their original precedence) but you can't extend the set.

I have only used one language that allowed you to define new operators : it solved the operator precedence problem by having only one level of precedence!
Thus 1 + 2 * 3 = 9 : if you wanted the conventional semantics you enforced it with parentheses : 1 + (2 * 3) = 7.

Too freaky for VHDL!

Answer (score 0):

**You can redefine new operators in the form of "Operator Overloading".**
As far as I am aware, you can't define entirely new operators.

See IEEE 1076 section 2.3.1

[image]

> Browsing the std_logic_1164.vhd source code I noticed the operator
> function names were all in quotes rather than just written out. Is
> that the difference?

You are allowed to put quotes around any identifier.  Its not just used for operator overloading.  The typical use is if you want an identifier that contains characters that are not normally part of a legal identifier.  An asterisk is not allowed as part of an identifier.  If it were, then you wouldn't be able to tell if A*B was a signal with name "A*B", or signal A times signal B.  Therefore when overloading an operator such as "*" one uses quotes around the identifier.